# Directory Exist on network path

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I'm working on a smart device and using .Net Compact framework 2.0.
When I'm mounting a drive on smart device then I'm able to see the mount drive with name "pc:" on device.

When I'm trying to see if any directory exist on drive using this method

`bool result = System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir); // Always getting false`

But when I manually navigate to that drive then I see that directory is there.

Please tell me how to do it so that I can get true value when mount drive is up and get false value when mount drive is not present.

P.S.:   mount directory path is like "pc:\Newname"

Comment: Have you tried "pc:\\Newname"?

Comment: Yeah I have tried but It's also not working.

Comment: Discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a25a395-ebcd-4262-9f68-5573e2feb350/how-to-create-a-map-network-drive-connection) indicates that you might have some luck with `@"\\pc\Newname"`

Comment: @jim Mischel: I have tried this also but didn't work for me.

Comment: Can anyone Help me for this because It's very urgent for me.